# Python ImportError Cannot Import Name

Tags: python

In my working folder I have a file called *exceptions.py*, which contains only:

```
class ParseException(Exception):
    pass

class QueryException(Exception):
    pass
```

In the same folder I have a file, lets call it *my_script.py*

In *my_script.py*, when I do `from exceptions import ParseException` I get an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name ParseException

I cannot figure out what's going on here. I've never seen this error before, and when I looked it up I mainly see problems with circular dependencies, but I don't have any here...

Comment: Works for me, are you sure there is no typo in either the filename of `exceptions` or in the import statement or the `ParseException` ?

Comment: Yeah not only have I double checked spelling, but I've also let my IDE auto do the import. Maybe I should just restart...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `exceptions` [module](http://effbot.org/librarybook/exceptions.htm) in your Python library which doesn't have the methods/classes you're trying to import. Change your file name to something different and it'll work.

Try the following yourself

```
>>> import exceptions 
# Works OK
>>> from exceptions import ParseException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name ParseException
>>> from exceptions import ImportError # Works OK too
```

Comment: I should have realized that was the problem. Thanks.